# Why can't haskell deduce this multi parameter type class?

Tags: haskell

I have two typeclasses

```
class Concatable a where
  empty :: a
  (<+>) :: a -> a -> a

class Concatable b => Output a b where
  out :: a -> b
```

and the following function

```
nl :: (Output a AnsiDark) => [a] -> AnsiDark
nl a = foldr addNl empty a
  where
    addNl :: a -> AnsiDark -> AnsiDark
    addNl ast org = doAddIf ast <+> org
    doAddIf :: a -> AnsiDark
    doAddIf ast = if out ast == sDedent
                      then out ast
                      else out ast <+> sNewline
```

(`AnsiDark` implements `Concatable`, `sDedent` is a constant of type `AnsiDark`)

as well as the following language extensions enabled (which might not even relate to the problem, I'm fairly new to these complex type related problems)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

and I get the following error:

```
../src-hs/ANSITerm.hs:65:22: error:
    • Could not deduce (Output a1 AnsiDark) arising from a use of ‘out’
      from the context: Output a AnsiDark
        bound by the type signature for:
                   nl :: forall a. Output a AnsiDark => [a] -> AnsiDark
        at ../src-hs/ANSITerm.hs:59:1-44
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘out ast’
      In the expression: out ast == sDedent
      In the expression:
        if out ast == sDedent then out ast else out ast <+> sNewline
```

I don't quite get why haskell isn't able to deduce `a`... I would have resorted to using type annotations with `out` like so

```
out @a @AnsiDark
```

but type annotations don't seem to work with type variables. So... what exactly is my problem here? And how could I solve it?

Comment: `(Output a1 AnsiDark)` is a constraint. The compiler is trying to match that to an instance for `Output`, so that it knows how to implement `out`. You appear to have no instances at all. What do you expect `out ast` to produce if you haven't given an equation for it?

Comment: The message you'd get from the Hugs compiler would be `Unresolved overloading`. Would that be a better explanation? This is not a "complex type related problem". (GHC's messages in general expect that you're trying to do something really fancy. They're rather too full of giddy type theory for newbies IMO.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
nl :: (Output a AnsiDark) => [a] -> AnsiDark
...
    where
    doAddIf :: a -> AnsiDark
    ...
```

The `a`s that appear on these two lines are *not the same*.  It is as if you had written:

```
nl :: (Output x AnsiDark) => [x] -> AnsiDark
...
    where
    doAddIf :: y -> AnsiDark
    ...
```

Since you are using `out` in `doAddif` you need to add the `Output` constraint to its signature (I believe it will work if you remove the signature, since the correct signature will be inferred).

You might also be interested in the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.  With this enabled, if you write

```
nl :: forall a. (Output a AnsiDark) => [a] -> AnsiDark
```

then you can refer to *that* `a` in signatures in the `where` clause as well as in type applications like the `out @a @AnsiDark` you tried.